# How to select data that doesn't exist in other query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select from table data but i want the result not exist in this select.

```
(SELECT * FROM data WHERE category = 'A' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM data WHERE category = 'B' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)`
```

So there are no row that been selected double.
Fiddle with [sample data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqaisid2d3MNbv8HCXoGud/1).

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: No row *can* be duplicated because `category` is different on each row.

Comment: Explain some logic about what you are trying to do. Otherwise, we don't know what is wrong with current query

Comment: If you have duplicate data (within the same `category`) then perhaps a `SELECT DISTINCT` will work for what you want.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thank you, i will improve my question
Here the demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqaisid2d3MNbv8HCXoGud/1

Comment: Demo is good but we still dont know what is wrong or what result you want

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I want to select from same table but besides the result from my query above

Comment: Ok, I get it now. But doesn't make much more sense choose 8 items random and then select everything else. What is the propose of this function? Can you give us some context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE category = 'A' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE category = 'B' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
  ) t 
  WHERE t.id = t1.id AND t.category = t1.category  
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f7a5165cc93bea495eafb854acc77e05).

Comment: I wonder do the RAND() are executed only once or for each row?

Comment: @Sheehan Check the demo and copy and paste the code.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza once

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza once for every row, in each subquery.

Comment: @Sheehan if the column `id` is unique you can remove ` AND t.category = t1.category` from the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where id not in ( 
  select id from ( 
    (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = 'A' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)     
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.category = 'B' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
  )
as t)
```